# Getting Uncaught TypeError: ...default is not a constructor - from Vue component

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, node-modules, vue-loader

Hi I get following error in chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _firebase2.default is not a constructor
```

when I use following code in **Fire.vue** (webpack vue-loader) component:

```
var db = new Firebase(this.rootUrl)
```

Here is the full code of my **Fire.vue**:

```
<template lang="jade">
  h2 Hello from: {{ component_name }}
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Firebase from 'firebase'
Vue.prototype.$consoleLog = function (args) { console.log(args) }

export default {
  props: {
    rootUrl: {
      default: 'https://boiling-heat...', // here will be url of database
      type: String
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      component_name: 'Firebase component!'
    }
  },
  ready () {
    var db = new Firebase(this.rootUrl) // <- this causes error
    this.$consoleLog(db)
  }
}
</script>
```

It has nothing to do with my `rootUrl` property, it's just to keep the code clean. I'm not sure if that is caused by error in Firebase package or did i miss something when importing it for my component.

Answer (score 7):

`is not a constructor` means `Firebase` object should not be called with `new` keyword.

A quick glance at the [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) page gives the following example of Fireabse initialization:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var app = firebase.intializeApp({ ... });
```

Comment: Thanks. I got my `new Firebase` from https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/04/vuefire-firebase-meets-vuejs_0.html I will try the code from official npm module doc and mark your answer as accepted if it works.