# Firebase: .default is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial).

I'm currently stuck at the step which introduces react context to firebase.

This code block is the source of the current problem:

```
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> TypeError:_components_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default is not a constructor

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360610/getting-uncaught-typeerror-default-is-not-a-constructor-from-vue-component), which relates to Vue but says that the cause of an error with .default is not a constructor (not the rest of it), is because  Firebase object should not be called with new keyword.

I tried removing new, but that generates an error message that says:

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the unusual way that the tutorial configures the app for firebase - which is with a class that uses a constructor (still don't understand why this is done this way):

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.database();
  }
export default Firebase;
```

Does anyone using Firebase with React know how to use the context API and if you do, have you found a way around this problem?

The firebase config setup files are:

index:

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './Context';
import Firebase from '../../firebase.1';
export default Firebase;
export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase };
```

context:

```
import React from 'react';
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
export default FirebaseContext;
```

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254387/firebase-auth-is-giving-me-an-error-when-trying-to-resolve-a-promise), which looks like it might have been trying to follow the same tutorial.

That approach requires that I add back the auth method in the firebase.1.js config file so that it now looks like this:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = app.auth();
    // this.db = app.database();

    // this.db = app.firebase.database()
    this.db = app.firestore();

  }  

  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  
}
```

Then, the submit handler in the form is like this:

```
handleCreate = values => {
    values.preventDefault();

    const { name, email, password } = this.state;

    Firebase
    .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
      return this.auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((res) => {
        Firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(res.user.uid).set({
          email: values.email,
          name: values.name,
          role: values.role,
          createdAt: Firebase.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }).then(() => this.history.push(ROUTES.DASHBOARD));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  };
};
```

When I try this, I don't get any errors, but the form does not submit - it just hangs.

**NEXT ATTEMPT**

Since the FirebaseContext.Consumer includes a line with firebase in lowercase, I tried all of the same steps above, but replacing title case Firebase with lower case firebase. I also tried this.firebase (I don't know why) and this.props.firebase (I have seen other posts try that but still don't know why).

None of these approaches work either.

When I try to console.log(Firebase) above the FirebaseContext.Provider, I get this a big log with lots of drop down menus that starts with this:

> FirebaseAppImpl {firebase_: {…}, isDeleted_: false, services_: {…},
>   tokenListeners_: Array(0), analyticsEventRequests_: Array(0), …}
>   INTERNAL: {analytics: {…}, getUid: ƒ, getToken: ƒ,
>   addAuthTokenListener: ƒ, removeAuthTokenListener: ƒ}

One of the drop down menus inside this log is labelled "options_" and includes my firebase app credentials.

Comment: How do you export that Firebase class / import in the main code?

Comment: I updated the post to add these details.

Comment: '../../firebase.1' contains the Firebase class code above right?

Comment: It seems that Firebase is undefined. At least from the error. Can you console.log the value of `Firebase` in the main code that imports it and throws the error? (for example just above `ReactDOM.render`) Is it showing the class as expected?

Comment: Yes- firebase.1 contains the firebase config setup with that class.

Comment: The log returns the class: class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.auth(); // …

Comment: I see the  Firebase class misses a closing bracket before export, I guess it's there in the actual file?

Comment: Yes - it's in the file, I just have so many commented lines of different things I've tried in the config file, before I close the method

Comment: does it look strange that the console sows all that webpack_imported bit in between firebase and auth?

Comment: That code is transpiled by webpack/babel into one (or splitted) ES5 bundle that you have in your app. It's normal that the values exported from other modules gets prefixed.

Comment: If you try the Firebase class with only the constructor, copied in the main file (no import), does it work? Otherwise,  If you do `const contexValue = new Firebase();` and then use that `contextValue` in the context prop, does it work?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean - as in, don't use the FirebaseContext?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203742/discussion-between-pandaiolo-and-mel).

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related to the problem [in my recent other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244570/1148030).

I managed to get `new Firebase` working by simplifying the import/export setup.

In the react app the imports are now:

```
import { FirebaseContext } from './components/context';
import Firebase from './components/firebase';
```

Those imports and the `new` work after I replaced the complicated "import and re-export" code in the `components/firebase.js` with simply the definition for the `class  Firebase` from the tutorial.

After this another error `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).` pops up, but that could be because I didn't follow the whole tutorial and some configuration is missing.

Replicating everything you are dealing with is quite difficult without having the full source of your project.

Here is the test `App.js` I used after the `npx create-react-app react-firebase-authentication` and after installing `firebase`.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { FirebaseContext } from './components/context';
import Firebase from './components/firebase';

function App() {
    const foo = new Firebase()
    return (
    <div className="App">
      ... omitted ...
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll have time to look into what you've done tomorrow. The * import comes with a firebase warning not to use it other than in development, so I'm trying to import the specific packages. I'll look tomorrow and come back to you.

Comment: I found a solution in removing properties on the firebase consumer. I didn't use your solution, but giving the points to you as a thanks for trying to help

Comment: @Mel Thanks! (Not sure how legit that is.) Can you edit my post with details? Or better yet make your own answer describing the change in relation to the tutorial. (Answering your own question is perfectly fine. I do it all the time and its ok in the SO FAQ)